# Create if formula

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets

I would like to create a cell call points. It looks at another cell (i8) and if that cell is greater then 15 it gets 2 points. If it is between 16-25 it gets 1 point, if it is greater then 25 it gets zero points.

---

This is for google sheets if value is
=<15 gets 2 pts
16-25 gets 1 pt

> 25 gets zero points

Comment: Apart from no language being specified, the logic doesn't make sense. All those numbers are greater than 15.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow lisa. please have a [tour] and learn [ask]. you could reply comments by clicking "Add a comment" below.

Comment: you can solve your problem using nesting ifs (something like `=IF(I8>25;0;IF(I8>16;1;2))`), however as paddy said, your problem doesn't really make much sense at a glance. does 16 gets 2 points or 1 point? what about 26 as its also bigger than 15?

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=IF(I8<=15; 2;
 IF(I8<=25; 1;
 IF(I8>25; 0)))
```